Feature code organization when u need to use function of another feature
I am just reading and thinking about feature organization project structure and I really like it. Article here: https://dev.to/jamesmh/the-life-changing-and-time-saving-magic-of-feature-focused-code-organization-1708
But when I go deep into thinking, I have no idea how to solve problem when one feature can't use another feature. In approach i was using now, I created service that handled useful methods used accross all app. So u don't have to write it for each feature again and again, it was shared (and for me it's big benefit of programming).
But now, I create features for GetArticle, UpdateArticle, CreateArticle, and each of this feature require some part of Authorzation and Authentation service, checking user role etc... (lets call it shared funcionality) and with feature approach I should code it again and again in every single feature and doesn't share it.
The more complex feature is, the more code repeating you are. Example of CreateOrderFeature, that is using funcionality of features like (CheckProductAvailability, SendStockRequest, SendOrderEmail...)
Can somebody tell me if these is solution for this in feature concept, or it is really disadvantage of this approach to write repeated code again and again inside every feature?
Thanks for your time.
